# How to format every page of a document using a particular style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, header-footer, numbering, margins

I'd like to create a template as displayed in the picture included here. The template should be such that, each page in my LaTeX document will have this same pagestyle; i.e., the margins should display on each page and every page should be separated by a line and divided into two equal parts so that the upper half is used for setting questions and the lower half for answering them. The box at the bottom right corner will contain a summary of one's answers; being it in the form of multiple choice or one that requires short responses. I'm new to LaTeX and hence have not been able to wrap my head around this. Any help would be very much appreciated!!! [image]

Comment: You might want to look at the tcolorbox package. It's quite powerful for such things.

Answer (score 3):

A proposal based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193605/121799).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193605/121799
\newcommand{\FancyPage}[4][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[anchor=north west,text
  width={\textwidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}] at 
  (current page text area.north west) (topnode-\thepage)
   {
     \vbox to 0.486\textheight{#2\vfill}
  };
  \node[below=0pt of topnode-\thepage,text width={\textwidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}},
  yshift=\the\pgflinewidth](bottomnode-\thepage){
     \vbox to 0.486\textheight{#3\vfill}
  };
  \node[anchor=south east,text
  width=0.3\textwidth,xshift=\the\pgflinewidth,
  yshift=3\pgflinewidth] (rightnode-\thepage) at 
  (current page text area.south east) {
     \vbox to 0.3\textheight{#4\vfill}
  };
  \draw (current page text area.south west) rectangle
  (current page text area.north east);
  \draw (current page text area.west) --  (current page text area.east);
  \draw (current page text area.south -| rightnode-\thepage.west) 
  |-   (current page text area.east |- rightnode-\thepage.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\FancyPage{\begin{center}
     Questions
     \end{center}
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item \dots
     \item \dots
     \end{enumerate}
}{
\begin{flushleft}
     Working area
     \end{flushleft}
     \dots
}{
Answers:
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item \dots
     \item \dots
     \end{enumerate}}
\clearpage   
\FancyPage{\begin{center}
     Questions
     \end{center}
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item Another question
     \item \dots
     \end{enumerate}
}{
\begin{flushleft}
     Working area
     \end{flushleft}
     \dots more stuff
}{
Answers:
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item \dots
     \item \dots
     \end{enumerate}}
\end{document}
```

This answer comes with a macro `\FancyPage{<top content>}{<bottom content>}{<right content>}` which creates a page similar to your screen shot.